# How to import excel and/or pkl files onto iPad pro Juno app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipad, openstack-juno

I’m learning to code Python on iPad. I’m using Juno. I was wondering if there’s any way to import excel and pickle files onto Juno so that I can do real data analysis on iPad without having to switch to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. The only restriction of iOS is that Juno can access only its own folder on the iPad. So you have to save the excel or csv file inside iPad's own Juno folder (I usually make a subfolder for each project) and then you can normally import the Excel sheet with

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'yourfile.xlsx')
```